# Unable to login to tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="madhukar" password="madhukar" roles="manager-gui, manager-script"/>
```

I have set the tomcat credentials with username and password, but I am unable to login to tomcat gui to manage the server running on localhost:8080

If anyone has encountered similar issue before or know to resolve it, please help me on it.

I have set the credentials for login to tomcat server, but its not letting me login to http://localhost:8080/manager/status

Help is appreciated.

I was expecting login to tomcat manager but it did not worked out.

Comment: Welcome to [main]! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See if removing the space between 'manager-gui' and 'manager-script' solves the problem. Actually, 'manager-gui' should suffice. Also check the 'catalina.out' log file for any hints.

Comment: added more details.